# why the Pyqt application implemented and worked well in VISTA can not run in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, pyqt

all, I implemented an application in my laptop (vista) with PyQt and it worked quite well. But if I want to run it in a desktop of Windows XP system, an error occured! It says the configuration was wrong. What is the reason (by this i mean does it matter which system I used??)and how to solve it please? thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

More info would be useful, but this sounds familiar to a problem I had when freezing apps using py2exe. Is this your exact error message?:

*The application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect.
Reinstalling the application may fix the problem.*

I managed to get around this by installing the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en) from http://download.microsoft.com.

This was an error I had when using py2exe. After switching over to [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), which bundles the runtimes during freezing, the problems went away without having to install the C++ runtimes on an XP machine. There may even be a way to bundle the runtimes using py2exe, but I've not looked.

Comment: Right! That message was shown to me also. I will try to fix it then, thank you !!

Comment: Please post back here about how you get on. I fixed it as above, but if that doesn't work for you or if you find another workaround it would be useful to know about.

Comment: Hi, I got a problem in using the PyInstaller for converting my application to an executable one on Windows. It seems one file depends on another and the final exe file was unable to run due to the lack of that file... don't know what was going on...By using Py2exe, I am installing a vc++ environment, and shall see how it works. Anyway, it worked fine in my boss' system, i will see tmr how it works in another computer... and I shall post the result here soon~~cheers